# Composer upadate, could not find the config file

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I'm new to laravel & composer, I used composer to download a package for L5, when I made changes on the json file, i did a composer update & got this following issue

```
D:\wamp\www\laravel>composer update
Composer could not find the config file: C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the http://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
```

Please any idea on how to solve this ?

Comment: from which dir do you rum the command?

Comment: what changes did you make to your composer.json?

Comment: @WouterJ runing it from my laravel directory.

Comment: @Victor I only added a require line, way/generators.

Comment: i guess your composer.json is missing ? 

install another copy of laravel using the installer or type "composer create-project laravel/laravel" to create a new one then copy the composer.json to your working project folder or you can simply copy just the composer.json from the laravel repo on git hub https://raw.githubusercontent.com/laravel/laravel/master/composer.json make sure you're using the correct version.

Answer (score 1):

Found this solution, seems to work:

```
COMPOSER=composer.json composer update
```

looks like it's a common issue.

https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/3514

https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer

This command updates the global variable COMPOSER, allowing to change default settings like the location of composer.json file or the vendor path, for example.

Comment: I tried this one, but it gives me an error 

 `[InvalidArgumentException]
 Command "=composer.json" is not defined.`

Comment: this should not be working anyway. i've never tried it but even as a command it looks wrong.

Comment: The command does work and it's actually documented by composer developers.